# Issue when installing Delphi 10.3 Community Edition

Tags: delphi

When installing Delphi 10.3 Community Edition, it is showing the following errors at startup:

[image: exception EPackageError in module RTL]

[image: exception EPackageError in module RTL]

When loading is finished, the IDE does not present the project options, as shown in the following image:

[image: There are no project options]

Actions I took:

I uninstalled and reinstalled through Windows' program manager, but the same errors were presented.

I redid the procedure above and did a manual cleaning in regedit, but the same errors presented after reinstallations.

I downloaded the 10.4 trial version and installed it, but the same errors were presented.

Finally, I installed it on a virtal machine and I didn't get these errors. This shows that the problem is related to my computer, but I don't know what actions I can take to try to eliminate these errors anymore.

Any suggestion?

Comment: submit a support request to the vendor

Comment: You really should contact Embarcadero for support on this. But, in English those error messages are saying "The specified module could not be found". So either those BPLs are not on your system at the paths shown, or a file they depend on is missing. Try using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what file is actually failing to be found.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Make sure it is FULLY up-to-date including 20H2 release. Disable any security product (anti-virus or other). Start the installer as administrator. Before reinstalling, delete Program Files (x86)\embarcadero\Studio\20.0 and same in document and settings.

Comment: Remy, thanks for your answer, with the help of SysInternals Process Monitor I was able to discover that a Windows DLL was missing, probably in some software uninstall this dll must have been deleted.

Comment: I'll be glad which DLL it is! And it is interesting that you create an answer yourself (or @RemyLebeau) of your question so that the next one searching for this issue found it.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMachadoClaro See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Be sure in your answer to specify which DLL it was, that was missing

Comment: Sorry for not giving the complete information before, the DLL that was missing from my system was olepro32.dll

Answer (score 1):

The issue found by the OP using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is that `olepro32.dll` was missing. Restoring the missing DLL solved the issue and Delphi 10.3 has been successfully installed.